# Is there a way to prevent switching layers when laying tracks in KiCAD?

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, pcb-layers

When I lay tracks in KiCAD on the back Cu layer (v5.1.0, Windows) I have the front Cu layer toggled invisible in the layer manager. I also have the selector arrow set to the back Cu layer.

I have the track tool selected and click on an empty bit of the board, if there is a track under the cursor on the front side it immediate makes the front side visible again and switches to the front layer which is incredibly annoying. Is there a way to switch this behaviour off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable this behavior by selecting the "High Contrast" display mode.  This will grey-out the non-selected layers and force interaction only with the active layer.

[image: High Contrast button]

Comment: Thanks. That is the last option I would have thought of checking. I sometimes wonder at these strange workarounds ...

Comment: Won't be needed in version 5.1.5:  https://git.launchpad.net/kicad/patch/?id=fc1fb7a590ebf2c7f959c14a8d0a67dc860f3491  We can only fix issues that we know about and no one reported this one yet. :)

Comment: Ah I kind of assume these things aren’t bugs and are needed for some workflow, how is it best to report these quirks?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad

Comment: @Brendan the high contrast mode has additional benefits. It not only disables accidentally working on the wrong layer but allows you to keep layers visible while them not being in the way (as they are shown in gray instead of colour)